# May a database be completely overwritten for n times without danger to truncate data?

Tags: mysql, database, overwrite

A simple and maybe too amateur question, but: is it ok for a table on the database to be consistently (for example, every day) completely overwritten?

I get the data for the whole year from the beginning until every new day/week/month. And you could just append the new months, but I fear that there are some new data for the past months in the file. So I want to overwrite my table every time I get a new file. But is it ok for the table? I mean can it somehow corrupt it?

**EDIT**:
the context of my question was that I overwrite data in RapidMiner tool, and I don't know exactly what method it uses for this. So I should probably speak to RapidMiner support about it.

Comment: This would probably depend on the database software

Comment: You really need to make this specific to an individual database implementation, and a specific overwrite mechanism. No general answer will be correct in all cases. (For instance, regularly overwriting a Datomic database would be a Really Bad Idea -- not due to corruption, but on account of storage requirements).

Comment: ...also, in selecting an update mechanism, your atomicity constraints matter greatly, as does the data size. (Do you need the database to always have usable data? Can the relevant table safely appear to be empty to anything running queries while the update process is in place? Do you need to worry about whether any preexisting long-running query can exist that blocks a table lock while your update process is in progress?)

Comment: BTW, the only hint that you're actually talking about a **SQL** database at all is the use of the word "table" (and it's just a hint, plenty of non-SQL databases still use tables). There are so many different kinds of databases in the world that this question is, without clarifying edits, ridiculously vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing historical data is a reasonable approach.  Before loading the new data, presumably you are doing one of these things:

- Truncating the existing table
- Deleting the rows
- Dropping the table

Only the second of these runs the risk fragmenting the table.  But that probably isn't a big deal when the data is being loaded in bulk.

The bigger issue is when historical data changes.  Then, your results for January may be different *because the data changes*.  This can be difficult to track, when you have deleted the older data.

The purpose of this answer is not to offer a solution to that problem (which is not part of your question).  It is simply to point out that there are probably other considerations beyond overwriting the table.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there's no way you can *corrupt* something specifically with this case, but it seems like a very strange behaviour overall.

I guess, you need some completely different of that you are using now. I didn't get the whole problem, maybe you can provide more algorithmical approach for your trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here a short summary.

1. It depends on database.

> For instance, regularly overwriting a Datomic database would be a Really Bad Idea -- not due to corruption, but on account of storage requirements. by @Charles Duffy

2. I have posted this question also on "Database Administrators" community site and got an answer, that a **RDBMS should not corrupt my data by overwriting data for many times**.
3. Deleting the rows can fragment the table, not deleting the table.

> "But that probably isn't a big deal when the data is being loaded in
>   bulk" (by @Gordon Linoff)

4. So the RDBMS will not get corrupted, but there are some other things you be aware of: storage requirements etc.

---

*Conclusion: there is no direct (negative) impact on the database by overwriting data completely for many times.*

Thank you all for your answers. The context of my question was that I overwrite the data not by myself, but in RapidMiner tool, and I don't know exactly what method it uses for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new ...
load `new`, not `real`
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

That keeps the table always available, even while you are reloading it.